# What is held in memory during the life of a CTE?

Tags: postgresql, memory, performance, postgresql-performance

Assuming a multi-read/multi-write CTE, what exactly is held in memory during the life of the statement?

Is all data except `RETURNING` data discarded at the end of each sub-statement?

Comment: This is very broad and needs a "why" and preferably some concrete examples. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm getting the most performance out of very large chained wCTE batches instead of many queries albeit also batched.  I wanted to get an idea of how resources would be consumed to accommodate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CTE term's output is accumulated into a TupleStore. A TupleStore may internally be in-memory or may spill to disk. See `src/include/utils/tuplestore.h` and `src/backend/utils/sort/tuplestore.c`, particularly the comment at the top of `tuplestore.c`.

For a wCTE that'll be the `RETURNING` output for that term.

To determine whether anything else is retained requires analysis of the memory contexts in which each CTE term is executed, as PostgreSQL uses a hierarchical memory context based allocator.  Here you need to look at `src/backend/executor/nodeCtescan.c`. It's pretty complicated, but a read of `CteScanNext` suggests that *the queries are often executing concurrently*, with one query consuming the results of another.

So. While memory might be freed at the end of each sub-statement (CTE term) there's no gurarantee that any of the CTE terms finish at any particular time.

Rephrasing your question:

> Is all in-memory data from a CTE term except `RETURNING` data discarded before the next CTE term executes

the answer is "no".

However, that doesn't mean PostgreSQL will keep piles of data in memory. It frequently discards rows as soon as it's done with them and never needs to see them again. It can spill big temporary results to tempfiles on disk. If it materialises, sorts or aggegates query output it will generally throw away the un-aggregated/un-sorted data after it finishes. etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I do try to examine the source myself, but it's like boost: extremely efficient, so sometimes I get lost and give up.  Thank you very much for pointing to the relevant source.

Comment: @JimBob Yeah... there's a whole lot to cover in the sources and it can be hard to know where to even start looking. I've been getting a handle on it over the last year or so of working on Pg, but there are still many things I don't have any idea where to start looking for. `git grep` and ctags/cscope are often pretty vital.